# trying to make a count down with out using date function

Tags: javascript

this is my code, it doesn't work I think the problem is what I'm returning in the function.
Please, help.

```js
var minutes = 25;
var seconds = 60;

function myFunction() {
  var start = setInterval(function() {
    if (seconds > 0) {
      seconds--;
    }
    if (seconds == 0) {
      seconds = 60;
      minutes--;
    }
    if (seconds == 0 && minutes == 0) {
      alert("done");
    }
    var time = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    return time;
  }, 1000);
  return start;
}
console.log(myFunction());
```

Comment: Aren't you kind of reinventing the wheel? Use the ``Date()`` constructor, and even Moment.js if you dont care for the ISO strings.

Comment: @AkramBadah - returning anything from `setInterval` handler is meaningless

Comment: Remove `return start`.

Comment: @igor is right, you can't return anything from setInterval, you need a callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the returns you have are pointless.  `console.log()` will only output one time.  You have to have `console.log()` inside of the `setInterval()` function to run multiple times.  You should also clear the interval to avoid any memory leaks.

Last, I also added in `minutes > 0` because otherwise seconds would be 60 and minutes would be `-1` when time has run out.

```js
var minutes = 25;
var seconds = 60;

function myFunction() {
  var start = setInterval(function() {
    if (seconds > 0) {
      seconds--;
    }
    if (seconds == 0 && minutes > 0) {
      seconds = 60;
      minutes--;
    } else
    if (seconds == 0 && minutes == 0) {
      clearInterval(start);
      alert("done");
    }
    var time = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    console.log(time);
  }, 1000);
}
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

### Description

Minor changes to show your code is working

**Bugs?**
- Requires a `minutes` and `seconds` variable be declared before myFunction is called, the rewrite takes these are parameters.
- Doesn't check if the variables are negative and thereby expects "valid" data from the user.
- Only allows for `console.log(time)`, the rewrite allows a function to be passed in for each `tick` and `onTimerComplete`

```js
var minutes = 25;
var seconds = 60;

function myFunction() {
  var start = setInterval(function() {
    if (seconds > 0) {
      seconds--;
    }

    if (seconds == 0 && minutes == 0) {
      alert("done");
      // added this to clear the timer on 0 minutes 0 seconds
      clearInterval(start);
      return;
    }
    if (seconds == 0) {
      seconds = 59;
      minutes--;
    }

    var time = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    // adding this as this is the function being repeated
    console.log(time);
  }, 1000);
}

myFunction();
```

---

### How I would rewrite this

```js
function timer(minutes, seconds, onTimerChanged, onTimerComplete) {
  var timerPointer = undefined;
  // if minutes is below 0 reset to 0
  if (minutes < 0) {
    minutes = 0;
  }
  // if seconds is set below 0 reset to 0
  if (seconds < 0) {
    seconds = 0;
  } else if (seconds > 59) {
    // this will add to minutes if too many seconds are passed
    minutes += Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    seconds = seconds % 60;
  }
  
  // this is the function to be called on each tick call
  // default: console.log
  if (onTimerChanged === undefined) {
    onTimerChanged = console.log;
  }
  if (onTimerComplete === undefined) {
    onTimerComplete = function() {
      console.log("done")
    };
  }
  // starts the timer
  this.start = function() {
      timerPointer = setInterval(tick, 1000);
    }
    // stops the timer
  this.stop = clearInterval(timerPointer);
  this.time = undefined;

  // function for each tick
  function tick() {
    if (seconds > 0) {
      seconds--;
    }

    if (seconds == 0 && minutes == 0) {
      // added this to clear the timer on 0 minutes 0 seconds
      clearInterval(timerPointer);
      if (onTimerComplete) {
        onTimerComplete();
      }
      return;
    }

    if (seconds == 0) {
      seconds = 59;
      minutes--;
    }

    // pads the numbers so they are always two digits
    this.time = padToTwo(minutes) + ":" + padToTwo(seconds);

    // if onTimeChanged exists call it
    if (onTimerChanged) {
      onTimerChanged(this.time);
    }
  }

  // padding the string to be two digits always
  function padToTwo(number) {
    if (number <= 99) {
      number = ("0" + number).slice(-2);
    }
    return number;
  }
}

// create the timer object
var test = new timer(-1, 500);
// start the timer
test.start();

// this would also work
// new timer(minutes, seconds).start();
```

Comment: Still no reason to have `return start;`

Comment: Also add that seconds should be set to 59 in `if (seconds == 0) {...}` otherwise the timer will drift one second each minute

Comment: @Robbie agreed hence what i would do is there

Answer (score 0):

Your code (almost) works. You just will have to wait 26 minutes to see the alert.

```
if (seconds == 0 && minutes == 0) {
  clearInterval(start);
  alert("done");
}
```

Comment: How does this have 2 upvotes (including my downvote).  This does not solve the problem at all.